# What is, in a non formal way, a simple ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, definition

What is a broad idea of what a simple ring is?

I am looking mostly for something intuitive rather than a formal mathematical answer.

For example the broad intuition of what a coset is, is that it's a subgroup that has been offset by an element of the bigger group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with simple groups? The idea behind a simple group is that its only normal subgroups are the entire group and the trivial group $\{1\}$. The idea behind a simple ring is much the same: the only two-sided ideals are $(0)$ and the entire ring.